# How do I make this in REACT-NATIVE? [NOTEBLOC]

Tags: javascript, react-native

im new in react-native and im making a notebloc to get started, the problem now is that I dont how to do this:

[image]

as you can see theres a title (input) and content (input), the problem now, is that i dont know how to do for insert an image and make a line break after it to continue to write below of it, should it be the same inputtext?

Answer (score 0):

you should put text input under the Image style theme by flex box

```
  <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:"column"}}>
     <Image .........../>
     <TextInput/>
  </View>
```

you can use https://flexbox.help
it will help you with that
but if you want put image in textiput you should use this component

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cn-richtext-editor
```

Comment: richeditor isnt it just for react web? or theres for react-native

Comment: no this package is for react native see the examples